# How to add onto a HTML attachment like href=""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, href

So I ran up onto a problem, how would I add text into the HTML attachment href. So, and example:

```
<a href="/example/script.js">...</a>
```

How would I change it too:

```
<a href="http://google.com/example/sript.js">...</a>
```

But, what if I had mutiple of these with different href's:

```
<a href="/example/sript-1251.js">...</a>
<a href="/example/sript-6346.js">...</a>
<a href="/example/sript-6836.js">...</a>
```

How would I change them all?

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`href` is called an attribute, and you can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) to change it

If you want to add same prefix to all of them then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a').attr('href', function (i, href) {
        return 'http://google.com' + href;
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2rTu8/)

Comment: great answer! didn't have a clue that jQuery attr can recieve a function! :)

Answer (score 1):

First find all the elements you wish to change and put them into an array (below, I'm just using all anchor tags, but you could do `getElementsByClassName` and give them all some class as to not affect every anchor tag on the page), then loop through them and append the code.

```
(function () {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var x = 0; x < anchors.length; x++) {
        anchors[x].href = "http://google.com" + anchors[x].href;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're appending the same string to the start of all anchor tags' HREF attribute within a particular DIV or other container (say it has ID `myDiv`), that's relatively easy:

```
$('#myDiv a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href', 'http://google.com' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```